# How can pass the List of dynamically generated input fields form from the view to controller in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, listview, model-view-controller, razor, foreach-loop-container

I have dynamically generated input fields but I am unable to model binding and pass the list of values view to controller when I post the data without list then mapped.when I post the form then I am getting null object, there is model binding issue

```
[HttpPost]public ActionResult PatientVitals(List<PatientVitals> pvitalsDetails)
{

    var enterBy = SessionHelper.GetLoggedInUserId();
    var patientVitals = new PatientVitals();
    var patient = (Session["Patient"] as Patient) ?? new Patient();
    var response = new AjaxResponse
    {
        Code = 400,
        MessageClass = "warning",
        ResponseText = "Unable to process"
    };
```

return response}

This is  Razor view with name space

```
@model List<PKLI.Model.Emr.PvitalsDetails>
```

this is Post form

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("PatientVitals", "EMR", FormMethod.Post))

{

<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Vitals/Measurement</th>
                    <th>Values</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Time Taken</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @if (Model != null) { 
                int j = 0;
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @item.Name
                            <input type="hidden" name="@Model[j].VitalsInformationId" id="vitalId+@j" value="@item.VitalsInformationId"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>                                                                   
                            <input placeholder="@item.Name" type="text" name="@Model[j].Readings"  id="Reading+@j"class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Unit
                            <input type="hidden" name="@Model[j].Unit" id="Unit+@j"class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                       <input type="text" name="@Model[j].Time" id="Time+@j"  class="form-control"placeholder="Enter Time" data-mask="99:99" />
                          </td>
                    </tr>
                    j++;
                }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

}

Comment: You need to go with ajax solution. Like Loop through your client side table and prepare list object to post via Ajax request.

Comment: Thank you Abid, I know ajax is alternate way, but is it not possible through model binding without ajax as I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using viewbag object instead of var.

```
viewbag.id = 0;
viewbag.enterby= SessionHelper.GetLoggedInUserId();
var patientVitals = new PatientVitals();
viewbag.patient = (Session["Patient"] as Patient) ?? new Patient();
var response = new AjaxResponse
{
    Code = 400,
    MessageClass = "warning",
    ResponseText = "Unable to process"
};
```

Comment: this is not answer , when I post the form then I am getting null object, there is model binding issue